# Как указать пространство имен по-умолчанию в шаблоне проекта Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, шаблоны-проектов

Имеется проект с пространством имен по умолчанию `Root.ProjectName`. Впоследствии проект экспортируется как шаблон с предварительным переименованием пространства имен `ProjectName` во всех файлах проекта в `$safeprojectname$`. Проблема в том, что после создания проекта, основанного на этом шаблоне, выкидывается исключение `MissingManifestResourceException`, а пространство имен по умолчанию меняется с `Root.ProjectName` на `ProjectName`, где ProjectName - это указанное пользователем имя проекта при создании.

Конечно, после ручного переименования все работает, но возникает вопрос: как принудительно указать в шаблоне, что пространство имен по умолчанию состоит не только из имени проекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании шаблона проекта, как правило, пространство имен в файлах переименовываются на `$safeprojectname$`. Но не всё можно заменить непосредственно в IDE.

Если используется составное пространство имен (например: `Root.ProjectName`), то после экспорта шаблона в файле `ProjectName.csproj` необходимо вручную переименовывать параметр `/Project/PropertyGroup/RootNamespace` (например на `Root.$safeprojectname$`). В этом же файле можно переименовать параметры `/Project/PropertyGroup/AssemblyName` и `/Project/PropertyGroup/DocumentationFile`.

Полный список поддерживаемых параметров шаблона можно посмотреть [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/eehb4faa.aspx).

Comment: у меня ругается на формат zip-файла при попытке сохранить измененный .csproj. VS2015, это косяк или так задумано и там не совсем zip? Как с этим бороться?

Comment: @rdorn я полностью распаковывал (7zip'ом) и тоже с ошибками в заголовках некоторых файлов. После обратного архивирования в ZIP Visual Studio шаблон приняла. Безусловно интересует этот момент. Может его нужно хитро упаковывать/распаковывать какой-либо утилитой?! Будем ждать знающих людей...

Answer (score 3):

Когда Вы создаёте (экспортируете) шаблон, имя, которое пользователь введёт при создании проекта с использованием Вашего шаблона подставляется вместо переменной `$safeprojectname$` во всех файлах проекта, в соответствии с содержимым файла `TemplateName.csproj` (где `TemplateName` это имя Вашего шаблона). Вот часть конфигурационного файла:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{$guid1$}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>$safeprojectname$</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>$safeprojectname$</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Обратите внимание на содержимое тегов `<RootNameSpace>` и `<AssemblyName>`. Если внутри вашего проекта будут вложенные директории, например, если корневое пространство имён шаблона - `Root`, а пространство имён внутри шаблона - `Foo`, соответственно,  у Вас имеется класс с именем `Root.Foo.SomeClass`, то при создании проекта по шаблону, если проект будет назван пользователем `MyRootSampleProject`, то полное квалифицированное имя класса `SomeClass` - `MyRootSampleProject.Foo.SomeClass`, в результате никаких исключений не будет и всё будет компилироваться корректно, ведь это вполне ожидаемое поведение, поскольку создание шаблона предполагает переименование КОРНЕВОГО пространства имён проекта, а за формирование этого имени отвечает сам пользователь, использующий Ваш шаблон. Если же Вы, как пользователь хотите, чтобы перед всеми именами классов в созданном по шаблону проекте был какой-либо префикс, то нужно ввести вместо, скажем, имени `MyRootSampleProject` что-то вроде `SolutionPrefix.MyRootSampleProject`. Принудительно указать префикс в шаблоне не представляется возможным, да и трудно представить ситуацию, в которой это действительно будет нужно.

Comment: По поводу ситуации когда нужен принудительный префикс - добавление нового проекта в солюшн большой библиотеки разбитой на модули например. Но в целом ответ понятен, ждем автора вопроса

Comment: @klutch1991 с использованием `$safeprojectname$` и `$projectname$` никаких проблем не возникает. Проблема была в том, что при экспорте проекта как шаблона, "скидывалось" пространство имен по умолчанию.